# Relationship entity used to create a hierarchy between objects of a single entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an Organization entity which can have a single parent and/or children. The hierarchy between organizations need to have extra columns (such as relationship type), so I created an entity OrganizationRelationship which is used for parents and also for children. I was able to get the children working with a OneToMany association but couldn't get the parent to work (which should use ManyToOne I guess).

I have an embeddable primary key as follows:

```java
@Embeddable
public class OrganizationParentChildPk implements Serializable {

  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  public Organization parentOrganization;

  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  public Organization childOrganization;

}
```

And then the relationship entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "ORGANIZATION_LK")
@AssociationOverrides({
    @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.parentOrganization", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID")),
    @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.childOrganization", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CHILD_ID"))})
public class OrganizationRelationship implements Serializable {

  @EmbeddedId
  private OrganizationParentChildPk pk = null;

  @Column
  private String relationshipType = null;

}
```

Finally, this is my organization entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "ORGANIZATION")
public class Organization extends Party {

  @Column(name = "NAME")
  private String name = null;

  // ???
  private OrganizationRelationship organizationParentRelationship = null;


  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pk.parentOrganization", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
      targetEntity = OrganizationRelationship.class)
  private Set<OrganizationRelationship> organizationChildRelationship = null;

}
```

What I would like is to make the parent relationship field also use the same *ORGANIZATION_LK* table if that is possible?

I thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Why not keep the information about the parent relationship on the Organization entity? If the structure is tree like, Organization may have three fields: Organization parent; String parentalType; and Set<Organization> children. Information about relationship with a child is kept with each children and about the own parent with the entity. Does this make sense to you? If so, do you still need help with the mapping? Please edit and clarify accordingly the question if that is the case.

Comment: If I am right you meant to get rid of the relashionship entity, and store the information directly in the organization entity. That is not possible according to my requirements, as there is also many other fields I didn't include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it working using the following annotation:

```java
  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "pk.childOrganization", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
      targetEntity = OrganizationRelationship.class)
  private OrganizationRelationship organizationParentRelationship = null;
```